# Decoding valgrind report

Tags: valgrind

Valgrind experts can help me out here with the valgrind report.

Ran c++ application with valgrind to detect memory leaks, and strangely the leak summary shows different output on different runs. Note that the c++ process was loaded uniformly in all the runs. Below is the summary for two executions:
In first execution:

```
==15767== LEAK SUMMARY:
==15767==    definitely lost: 355 bytes in 25 blocks
```

In second execution:

```
==00:00:14:19.929 24494== LEAK SUMMARY:
==00:00:14:19.929 24494==    definitely lost: 236 bytes in 8 blocks
```

Can someone tell why the number of blocks are varying?

Thanks in advance, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely that the process behaved differently (because of timing, thread scheduling, external resources, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. So, which one is the genuine leak?

Comment: Most probably both, but it is possible that all leaks result from the same bug.